# Create variable function arguments in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I know that my question illustrates a fundamental lack of understanding, but I have hacked together a sheet that almost works except...

I am importing data from googlefinance then operating on the data.  The problem is that the length of the data is not always the same.  So my problem boils down to this:

Assume column A and B contains data e.g. A1-A10 contains date and B1-B10 contains price, cell c1 contains a COUNT of the data in column A so I know how many data points.

`=TREND(B1:B10,A1:A10)` will result in a trend line if I get all 10 data points and fail if not

How can I modify the TREND function arguments so that "A10" is instead "A(0 + the contents of C1)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `ADDRESS()` and `INDIRECT`

- Cell C1 = count of the number of rows. This can be used to generate the second half of a range.

  - Let's assume that the value in C1 = 9.

**ADDRESS**

- `address($C$1,1,4,true)` = A9
- `address($C$1,2,4,true)` = B9
- add a prefix of "A1:" and "B1:" to generate the string value of the ranges
- `"A1:"&address($C$1,1,4,true)` = A1:A9
- `"B1:"&address($C$1,2,4,true)` = B1:B9

**INDIRECT**

- `INDIRECT` returns a cell reference specified by a string.

  - `indirect("B1:"&address($C$1,2,4,true))` - returns values in the range B1:B9
  - `indirect("A1:"&address($C$1,1,4,true))` - returns values in the range A1:A9

**TREND**

`=TREND(indirect("B1:"&address($C$1,2,4,true)),indirect("A1:"&address($C$1,1,4,true)))`

Comment: Really appreciate the clarity of your solution - thank  you

Comment: Glad it works for you. You might consider “accepting” the answer.